# インメモリの一般的な導入方法について

Tags: windows, postgresql

案件対応をしながらインフラを勉強中のものです。

要件として、「DBはPostgreSQL、インメモリで構築」というものがあります。
インメモリについては調べて、データをディスクの代わりにメモリ上に配置することで、DBアクセスを高速化する仕組みと理解しました。

ですが、その実装方法についてイメージが湧きません。

専用のキャッシュサーバーを立てて何らかのソフトを導入するものなのか、部品があってそれをDBサーバー自体に増設するようなイメージなのか。

わかりやすく教えていただけると助かります。
また、PostgreSQL環境で多い実装方法などがありましたら教えて下さい。

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: PostgreSQLにインメモリデータベースと呼べるだけの機能ってあるのですか？そもそも不可能な要件だったりしませんか。

Comment: 申し訳ありません、そもそもそこもわかっておりません。
インメモリとはPostgreSQL（データベース）の機能で実装するものなのでしょうか。

Comment: この案件でいう「インメモリ」の要件を挙げましょう。回答が出来ません。

Comment: まずは「インメモリで構築」という案件を出した方に(どういったものを想定しているのか)確認するのが一番な気がします。

Comment: 申し訳ありません、浅学のため、どのような情報が不足しているのかもよく理解できておりません。
「インメモリの要件」とは具体的にどのようなものが必要なのでしょうか。一口に「インメモリ」と言っても色々あるということなのでしょうか。
一般論で構わないのですが。

Comment: 一般論でどうしようもないので、「インメモリ」をどういう意味でつかっているかまずは書いた人に確認しましょうということですよ。たとえば、DBに問い合わせた結果を自前でメモリ上に保持することさしているのか、インメモリDBを利用することを示すのか、キャッシュとしてたとえばmemcashのような仕掛けを利用するのか（これは最初の話の亜種ですが）「一文一意」になっていないのでだれも答えられないし、発散しますということです。

Comment: 申し訳ありません。これだけのアドバイスをいただいてもやはりイマイチ理解ができておりません。
「DBに問い合わせた結果を自前でメモリ上に保持する」とは、そう動作するようにアプリ側で設計するということでしょうか。
「インメモリDBを利用」とは何らかのソフトを導入するということでしょうか。
「インメモリ」とは要はデータベースへのアクセスを高速化するための仕組みと理解していますが、その実現方法については、ソフト導入のようにアプリ側で対処、メモリやSSDを大量に積んでハード側で対処等、色々な実現方法があるということでしょうか。
要件を出した方に確認してみましたが、あまり詳しいわけではなく、「インメモリってのを実装すればDBアクセスが速くなるんでしょ？」くらいの認識でした。

Comment: PostgreSQLというのが仕様、インメモリというのは「なんらかの仕組みでDB部分のアクセスを高速化」と解釈した上で、指摘されている通りmemcachedやRedisに問い合わせ結果を保存する、というのが良いように思います。しかし、「一般的な方法」という質問がスタックオーバーフローの質問としては不適切に感じるので、クローズに投票します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

インメモリDBというのは、通常はディスク上に作られる領域をメモリ上に保存するDBのことです。必然的に、製品自体が「メモリ上にDBを構築する」機能を持っている必要があります。PostgreSQLには現時点でその機能はありません。

OS側でRAMディスクを使り、その上にDB領域を作るということも考えられなくはありません。データの永続化などは一切できないなど、まともな環境とは言いがたいですが、一応インメモリといえないこともないかな、とは思いますが、

> 「DBはPostgreSQL、インメモリで構築」

という要件がそれを満たすかは謎です。

一般的な要件ではありませんので、その要件を出した人に、想定している構成を提示してもらってください。

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql はディスク上に構築しないといけませんので、インメモリでは構築できないですね。

一応ググってみましたが、インメモリでPostgresqlを動かす製品を富士通が販売してるようですので 検討してみると良いかもですね。
https://www.fujitsu.com/jp/products/software/middleware/database/enterprisepostgres/

ただ、頼んだ方も詳しいわけではないのでしたら、これを望んでいるというのも考えにくいで、NOSQLのインメモリデーターベースとしてRedisを提案してみたら良いんじゃないですかね。

ただNOSQLなので、RDBMSが必要なら PostgreSQLとRedisを組み合わせれば良いと思います。
これらの ユースケースはまずググってみて、わからないことがあったらまた質問をしてみると良いと思います。